# sometime not deleting records from postgresql db using python client

Tags: python, postgresql, connection-pooling

Hi this is my postgresql client code using python and I am doing connection pooling because I was getting error of connection limitations . So issue is whenever I get new record and I want to delete it from db. so doing delete request. but sometimes it is not deleting and doing duplicate records in database . Did a lot of debugging but not able to find cause as it's happening sometime . Even tried same query in dbviewr and that is working fine .

```
 connection_pool = SimpleConnectionPool(
        host=database_host,
        port=database_port,
        database=database_database,
        user=database_user,
        password=database_password,
        minconn=5,
        maxconn=10,
    )

    with connection_pool.getconn() as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        check_id_query = "SELECT uuid FROM mytable WHERE name = %s"
        cur.execute(check_id_query, (account_id,))
        result = cur.fetchone()

        if result:
            uuid = result[0]
            print("ID:", uuid)
            scope_id_string = "AND cmetadata->>'scope_id' = '{}'".format(scope_id) if scope_id else ''
            clean_record_query = "DELETE FROM mytable2  WHERE collection_id = '{}' " \
                                 "AND cmetadata->>'node_type' = '{}' AND cmetadata->>'node_id' = '{}'  {}".format(uuid, node_type, node_id, scope_id_string)
            print(clean_record_query , "clean_record_query_")
            cur.execute(clean_record_query)
            conn.commit()
            if cur.rowcount > 0:
                print("Record deleted successfully.")
            else:
                print("No record found to delete.")
        else:
            print("No ID found for the given account_id.")
```